# Get internal storage size used by my application from App info

Tags: android, storage, android-debug, android-internal-storage

From my Android application I trying to get used internal storage. In other words I need to get storage value showing in App info (check screenshot image). I tried below code but I am getting less value than storage value showing in appinfo. Kindly help me with what I am missing.

[image: storage image]

```
   public void GetOccupyMemory() {
    total_usage = getFileDataSize() + getFolderSize();
}

public long getFileDataSize() {
    long size = 0;
    File filedir = getActivity().getFilesDir().getParentFile();
    for (File fdir : filedir.listFiles()) {
        if (fdir.isDirectory()) {
            long dirfiles = getSize(fdir);
            size += dirfiles;
        } else {
            size += fdir.length();
        }
    }
    return size / (1024 * 1024);
}

public long getFolderSize() {
    try {
        long apsize = new File(getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getActivity().getPackageName(), 0).sourceDir).length();
        return apsize / (1024 * 1024);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `GetOccupyMemory()` in Mb?

Comment: @nhoxbypass  getFileDataSize() is giving value as 44 MB and getFolderSize() as 23 MB total 67 MB. But in my application App info storage showing as 118 MB. (please Ignore screenshot I posted it is a another application app info screen)

Comment: Did you click the Storage row to see more detail about how the storage was used (such as data, app storage, cache,..)?